# Flutter: DateTime fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch shows one day less

Tags: flutter, datetime, unix

I get a time value from an API which is a unix value, but when i use `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch`, it shows one day less. I don't understand why. Please explain me what i'm doing wrong.

I think timezones made the problem, but i don't know how to fix it.

*Unix value from API*

```
1623283201 // 2021-06-10 0:00:01.000
```

*This is my code*

```dart
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch((json['time_last_update_unix']) * 1000);
print("This is the date " + date.toString()); // 2021-06-09 20:00:01.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date input carrying a time zone which is not your local timezone, you have to explicitly change the following bool value

```
bool isUtc = true
```

Default value is false and date is identified from your local timezone.
For more detail please refer this link
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html